# Identifying a socket contact - and finding a slightly larger size

Tags: pcb, connector, soldering

I have this socket contact:

[image]

(The image of the pin terminal to the right in only for size reference).

I have identified this socket contact as `AMPHENOL Wire-Wire/PCB Connector`.

The problem is I need this exact socket contact at a slightly larger size. I don't even know what size is the one I have.

Is there a place where I can order such socket contacts, in various sizes? I have difficulty sourcing them in my local market.

I know they come in different sizes, because I already have three different variants, however, they are smaller than my intended one.

[image]

**EDIT:** This is the diameter of the cylinder that I measured.

[image]

Comment: **1)** "I don't even know what size is the one I have." Is there a reason you can't measure it? For small internal diameters, cheap, very small twist drills (often sold with a pin vice) are available in sets. And the three different variants that you have might have specified their sizes when you ordered them. **2)** Could you change the other connector to a known size?

Comment: Those are not "connectors". Those are "socket contacts".

Comment: In a distributor's catalog those contacts willl be listed with the connector bodies that they fit.  They are not considered connectors by themselves, but are part of specific connector families, and are intended to be inserted into the appropriate connector bodies.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I measured the "cylinder" (not the edge, where it opens up - making it larger) and it is 2.5mm...

Comment: @user1584421 Is that the inside diameter or outside diameter? It's the mating surface that matters, so for a male contact it would be the outside diameter, and for a female contact the inside diameter is needed. (The other diameters of each will differ from the needed size by twice the wall thickeness.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I measured the cylinder on the outside of the female connector.. Therefore its the outside diameter of the cylinder. Its very difficult to measure the diameter of the male pin, because it is surrounded by plastic. However, I have to note that the 2.5mm female socket contacts were too small and had to be stretched in order for the male pin to fit in. I measured them post stretching and they were about 2.85mm. And the male pin was very hard to pull it out. Theredore I assume that ideally I need something even wider, perhaps 2.9mm (?)

Answer (score 4):

Those are socket contacts for a [pin and socket connector](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=pin_socket_conn) (my site).

Here are a few large-diameter sockets for pin and socket connectors:

- 0.14 inch/3.55 mm ID: https://www.digikey.com/short/0948w7br
- 0.094 inch/2.38 mm ID: https://www.digikey.com/short/t78fzddp
- 0.084 inch/2.13 mm ID: https://www.digikey.com/short/dtnp5081

Comment: Thank you! I measured the "cylinder" (not the edge, where it opens up - making it larger) and it is 2.5mm. I want a slightly larger one. I know that the word "slightly" is very vague, but are there ones close to that size? I have one at home that I have opened it up to accomodate exactly the size of the male connector I want. In a couple of hours, I will be able to report its size. (BTW, you have created an excellent tool).

Comment: "I will be able to report its size." - I'll check back in a  few hours. "you have created an excellent tool". Thank you!

Comment: I should be thanking you! I measured the diameter of the 2.5mm (originally) that I opened up to make room for my male connector. It is 2.85mm. However, it was hard to pull it out. So I probably need something slightly wider.

Comment: I edited the question, with a picture of the cylinder whose diameter I measured (to avoid any misunderstandings). Is there a socket contact, where that diameter is close to `2.85mm`? Also, when I open the Digikey links you provided, in the search options are `Wire Gauge` and `Contact Finish Thickness`. What quantity do I have to search, in order to find the diameter of the cylinder in the picture? Is this `Wire Gauge`?

Comment: Hello. Excuse me, but do you happen to know if a socket contact of about the size I want to is available?

Comment: Yes, probably. But it wold take me 1 hour of research, and I don't feel I can afford to put that time into it. Look here: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/circular-connectors/circular-connector-contacts/330, and https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/rectangular-connectors/rectangular-connector-contacts/331, and https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/contacts/multi-purpose/336

Comment: Thank you but you don't have to search for the particular one yourself! My question is what quality do I search for, assuming that I know the cylinder diameter. Regarding which cylinder I measured, it's the one with the red line in the second picture. In the website, the characteristics listed are `Wire Gauge` and `Contact Finish Thickness`. Is the diameter of the measured cylinder one of these?

Comment: > what quality do I search for -- the OD of a pin. Then buy the corresponding socket. The vendors do not list the pin OD. You have to look at the picture of each pin individually. If it's round, then open the mechanical drawing (pdf) and  check its diameter (hopefully, it's listed). That's what takes a long time.

Comment: Thank you! What does OD mean though?

Comment: Sorry. It means Outside Diameter. I should have spelled out.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend!